# callback from java to C++ through JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

i am facing a issue, i have a c++ executable, which is using a java jar file through JNI, Now i need to give a callback from java module to C++ module.(here C++ module is higher module while java one is lower module.) Any input will be appreciable.

Comment: I think you should clarify this question a little bit, it is not very clear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a native method in your java class, register that method in your C++ code using RegisterNatives of JNI, write that native wrapper method in your C++ code(like we do in java to C++ call). call your native method, u will get callback in C++ exe.

Answer (score 4):

If I get it right, you are calling a Java method from C++ through JNI and you would like to provide some way for the Java layer to call back into your C++ object. Did I get your question right?

The way I would do this is to pass a **pointer** to your C++ object as a **long** to your Java class:

```
class JavaClass {
    long nativeObjectPtr;

    // This is the function getting called from C++.
    void MyFunc(long ptr) {
        ...
        nativeObjectPtr = ptr;
    }

    ...
}
```

When you call `MyFunc` from C++, pass a pointer to your native object as a long:

```
MyClass* ptr = ...; // Pointer to your native object;
env->CallVoidMethod(javaObj, myFuncMethodID, (long)ptr);
```

In your Java class, create a **native** function which calls back into your native object:

```
// inside JavaClass
native void callBackIntoNative(long ptr);

void CallBackIntoNative() {
    callBackIntoNative(nativeObjectPtr);
}
```

And in the **C++ implementation** of your native function, simply **cast** the long to the type of your C++ class, and call the appropriate function on it:

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL JavaClass_callBackIntoNative(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jlong ptr)
{
    MyClass* o = reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>(ptr);

    // We have the pointer to our native object, simply call the needed function.
    o->Callback();
}
```

Of course you have to make sure that you native object does not get destroyed during the entire time to be able to call back into it.

Comment: hi, Mark your solution will not work, he is asking to get callback from java jar file to C++ exe, what you have shown will work when dealing with dll. in your case he will get linking error.

Comment: @user1808932 is right. But it is not much to do to get Mark's solution be finished. You just need to register your native method by calling method JNIEnv::RegisterNatives. See chapter 6 "Example 6: Callbacks and Instance Variables" of CodeProject article "Calling Java from C++ with JNI" (https://www.codeproject.com/articles/993067/calling-java-from-cplusplus-with-jni).

Comment: and how to get myFuncMethodID?